# Why was this question put "on hold"

Tags: discussion

**This is the question I am talking about:**

https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/28938/should-i-report-a-nurse-practitioner-for-malpractice-is-it-malpractice

The poster clarified in the comments why he/she thinks this is on topic and I agree mostly. Even though I can't answer the question I believe there have been plenty of parents in similar situations!

She/he states: ***"I am not looking for legal advice, but I wonder if any of you would do more than change doctor's offices?"***

I do think even a calming answer could help not only the poster but everyone with similar experiences who might come from google.

I didn't want to blow up the comments on the post even more, and it seemed the mod and the poster stated evrything there was to say from their perspective. But I would  love a clarifying answer!

*Side Note: I do think anongoodnurse and Willow Rex both usually give great content, and I don't mean to attack either one!*

Comment: Please explain the downvote! I am honestly really curious!

Comment: On meta, upvotes usually indicate agreement, downvotes disagreement. And they don't affect your rep.

Comment: I do know that they don't affect my rep, and I really don't care about rep anyway. I just like explanations :-)

Comment: Sorry - I don't know, was just hoping to give a steer as to possible explanations :-)

Comment: Thank you for trying!

Comment: I'm unsure of what kind of answer you want here. You stated we shared our positions in the comments, so you know why I closed it. Is your question about what is [on topic](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tagged "discussion" because I believe some people might think it is on topic, and others think it is not. But sadly the question didn't get much attention. I know what is "on topic" and for this question it isn't too clear. I have seen questions way less "on topic" being on hot.

Comment: Being on hot doesn't have anything to do with if a question is on topic or not. A number of poor-quality questions - from every stack site - make it to HNQ.

Answer (score 4):

While I haven't voted on that question at all, I think the biggest problem with it is that it really isn't a parenting question.  Now before I get downvoted to oblivion, let me explain.

As I read it, the OP went to a doctor's office, overheard a nurse say something she didn't like, tried to address it and didn't get a satisfactory response.  Then the OP asks "What should I do?".  Well, that question doesn't really have a parenting angle to it.  It's very open ended and, given the context, leans more towards an interpretation of "how do I deal with this nurse / doctor's office?"  That's a pretty general question and not really parenting specific.  The fact that this took place at a pediatrician's office seems very tangential to the question being presented.  Replace "pediatrician's office" and "comments about spanking" in the original post with "any other doctor's office" and "comments about something offensive (possibly racist, sexist, medical practices you disagree with, etc.)" and the problem, answers and the question presented really don't change that much.

Now if the question had more to do with the OP's daughter, it would likely be a better fit.  For example, if the question presented was

> I took my daughter to her doctor's office the other day.  A nurse
>   there made a comment to another parent that he should discipline his
>   child by spanking.  I was very upset by this and have decided to do
>   {X}.  How do I explain to my daughter why I was so upset?

Or

> I took these steps to try and address the situation, but it didn't
>   work out the way I wanted.  This isn't going to stop me from fighting
>   for the things I believe in.  However, I am having a hard time
>   explaining to my daughter how not to get discouraged when things like
>   this happen.  How can I better explain to her the need to always stand
>   up for what you believe in?

Or

> When all this happened, it really upset my daughter.  How can I help
>   her get over this?

Or ...

This or any number of variants involving the daughter here would be a far better fit for the site.  As it stands, it is really more of a general life question that happens to involve a child.

Comment: +1 you are totally right, I did try to edit the question twice to make it more on topic because I think it is a really interesting question, but it didn't seem to be what the OP had in mind. Sometimes it really ends up to be the way a question is phrased. But that has been discussed quite often, similar to this: http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/226/would-we-accept-questions-about-parents?rq=1 Thank you for your answer :-)